# How and why does signal SIGABRT occur when running this code?

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

When I run my app, a function gets called in a view controller and when that happens I get signal `SIGABRT`.

How to solve this?

Function :

```
func setRootViewController()
{
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil
    {
        let tabVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabVC") as! TestViewController
        view.window?.rootViewController = tabVC
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    else
    {
        let welcomeVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.welcomeVC) as! ViewController
        view.window?.rootViewController = welcomeVC
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

When it crashes I get this in the console area :

> 21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac4241
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac416c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76     23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ac3944 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180  24  CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff23abe64f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263  25  CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff23abde36 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438     26  GraphicsServices
>   0x00007fff37f64bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65   27  UIKitCore
>   0x00007fff46d562a3 UIApplicationMain + 1621   28  Do It !
>   0x000000010f1b654b main + 75  29  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff51175cf5 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: Can you show the full error? Guessing from this I’d say one of the force casts `as!` is responsible.

Comment: Which line is causing the crash exactly? And you don't have more logs above that error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid force unwraps. Try this:

```
func setRootViewController() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        if let tabVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabVC") as? TestViewController {
            view.window?.rootViewController = tabVC
            view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else {
            print("TabVC doesn't exist or is not a TestViewController")
        }
    } else {
        let welcomeVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.welcomeVC)
        // you don't need to cast welcomeVC to a ViewController. 
        view.window?.rootViewController = welcomeVC
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have any follow up questions.